# I've got some troubles with return

Tags: javascript, html

I have a trouble: when button onclicked, I need to return position of a block and hold it till next onclick. On next click, I need to take position and change it again and hold its number. And make it for eternity xD. But I've done something wrong. Please help.
And one thing more: I need to make a reset position by clicking reset button. Reset must be to the 1.

```js
window.onload = function core() {
  // creating elements
  let platform = document.createElement('div');
  platform.setAttribute('id', 'platform');
  document.body.appendChild(platform);
  let up = document.createElement('button');
  up.setAttribute('id', 'up');
  up.setAttribute('class', 'actionButton');
  document.body.appendChild(up);
  document.getElementById('up').innerHTML = 'up';
  let down = document.createElement('button');
  down.setAttribute('id', 'down');
  down.setAttribute('class', 'actionButton');
  document.body.appendChild(down);
  document.getElementById('down').innerHTML = 'down';
  let left = document.createElement('button');
  left.setAttribute('id', 'left');
  left.setAttribute('class', 'actionButton');
  document.body.appendChild(left);
  document.getElementById('left').innerHTML = 'left';
  let right = document.createElement('button');
  right.setAttribute('id', 'right');
  right.setAttribute('class', 'actionButton');
  document.body.appendChild(right);
  document.getElementById('right').innerHTML = 'right';
  let reset = document.createElement('button');
  reset.setAttribute('id', 'reset');
  reset.setAttribute('class', 'actionButton');
  document.body.appendChild(reset);
  document.getElementById('reset').innerHTML = 'reset';
  // binding platform
  let count = 0;
  let defaultPosition = 1;
  for (let i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
    let grid = document.createElement('button');
    grid.setAttribute('id', i);
    grid.setAttribute('class', 'eachGridBlock');
    document.getElementById('platform').appendChild(grid);
    count++;
    if (count === 10) {
      let newLine = document.createElement('br');
      document.getElementById('platform').appendChild(newLine);
      count = 0;
    };
  };
  // waiting for action
  document.getElementById(defaultPosition).setAttribute('class', 'focusedBlock');
  console.log(defaultPosition);
  document.getElementById('up').onclick = function() {
    processUp(defaultPosition)
  };
  document.getElementById('down').onclick = function() {
    processDown(defaultPosition)
  };
  document.getElementById('left').onclick = function() {
    processLeft(defaultPosition)
  };
  document.getElementById('right').onclick = function() {
    processRight(defaultPosition)
  };
  document.getElementById('reset').onclick = function() {
    processReset(defaultPosition)
  };
  // action functions
  function processUp(positionX) {
    let nowPosition = positionX;
    if (nowPosition <= 10) {
      alert('you cant step here');
    } else {
      let nextPosition = nowPosition - 10;
      document.getElementById(nowPosition).setAttribute('class', 'eachGridBlock');
      document.getElementById(nextPosition).setAttribute('class', 'focusedBlock');
      positionX = nextPosition;
    };
    console.log(positionX);
    return positionX;
  };

  function processDown(positionX) {
    let nowPosition = positionX;
    if (nowPosition >= 91) {
      alert('you cant step here');
    } else {
      let nextPosition = nowPosition + 10;
      document.getElementById(nowPosition).setAttribute('class', 'eachGridBlock');
      document.getElementById(nextPosition).setAttribute('class', 'focusedBlock');
      positionX = nextPosition;
    };
    console.log(positionX);
    return positionX;
  };

  function processLeft(positionX) {
    let nowPosition = positionX;
    if (nowPosition === 1 || nowPosition === 11 || nowPosition === 21 || nowPosition === 31 || nowPosition === 41 || nowPosition === 51 || nowPosition === 61 || nowPosition === 71 || nowPosition === 81 || nowPosition === 91) {
      alert('you cant step here');
    } else {
      let nextPosition = nowPosition - 1;
      document.getElementById(nowPosition).setAttribute('class', 'eachGridBlock');
      document.getElementById(nextPosition).setAttribute('class', 'focusedBlock');
      positionX = nextPosition;
    };
    console.log(positionX);
    return positionX;
  };

  function processRight(positionX) {
    let nowPosition = positionX;
    if (nowPosition === 10 || nowPosition === 20 || nowPosition === 30 || nowPosition === 40 || nowPosition === 50 || nowPosition === 60 || nowPosition === 70 || nowPosition === 80 || nowPosition === 90 || nowPosition === 100) {
      alert('you cant step here');
    } else {
      let nextPosition = nowPosition + 1;
      document.getElementById(nowPosition).setAttribute('class', 'eachGridBlock');
      document.getElementById(nextPosition).setAttribute('class', 'focusedBlock');
      positionX = nextPosition;
    };
    console.log(positionX);
    return positionX;
  };

  function processReset(positionX) {
    let nowPosition = positionX
    let nextPosition = 1;
    document.getElementById(nowPosition).setAttribute('class', 'eachGridBlock');
    document.getElementById(nextPosition).setAttribute('class', 'focusedBlock');
    return positionX;
  };
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#plarform {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #222222;
}

.eachGridBlock {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000044;
  border: 0;
}

.focusedBlock {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #9900ff;
  border: 0;
}

.actionButton {
  border: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #999999;
  color: #222222;
  outline: none;
}

.actionButton:hover {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I cannot think of more unreadable core. Perhaps the odd line break and comment?

Comment: Please only add the bare essentials.

Comment: Look at the code's comments. I think it's enough commenting. Just need to return position value and use it when some button clicked again.

Comment: Look at the //action functions

Comment: 1. 4 comments stating the obvious. 2.A lot of code for us to decipher. 3. Where is the HTML. 4 Perhaps reproduce in jsfiddle et al.

Comment: @EdHeal _I cannot think of more unreadable core._ You haven't seen nothing yet. I've seen something like this, lots of createElements, setting properties and attributes, but with 20x more lines in a single block.

Comment: @EugeneZolotuhin The HTML is in the JavaScript. All the stuff at the beginning creates elements and appends them to the DOM.

Comment: This looks like an entire feature. Even has the css init. Please only add what we need to look at

Comment: The return value of an event handler function isn't used. If you need to save the value, assign it to a global variable.

Comment: Just answer this: 1. I stored a variable defaultPosition. 2. I need to change it's value after each clicked button and store it.

Comment: You never assign to `defaultPosition` in any of the functions.

Comment: Barmar, could you code this? Not clearly understand. But I'll think about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update `defaultPosition` when you call the functions, e.g.

```
document.getElementById('right').onclick = function() {
    defaultPosition = processRight(defaultPosition)
};
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Just a second please, I'll try

Comment: Oh my, It works!! Thank you so much) I'll learn this problem and understand it!)